# AccessibilityService dispatched gesture stops on touch of another part of the screen

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

This is my java code to dispatchGesture.

```
    GestureDescription.StrokeDescription clickStroke =  new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, DURATION,true);
    GestureDescription.Builder clickBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
    clickBuilder.addStroke(clickStroke);
    clickBuilder.build();
    GestureResultCallback callback = new AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);


                Log.d(TAG, "gesture completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);


                Log.d(TAG, "gesture cancelled");
            }
        };

        return MouseAccessibilityService.this.dispatchGesture(clickBuilder.build(), callback, null);
```

i have set willContinue to true . So the stroke is dispatched , but when the user touches anywhere else on the screen, the gesture stops.

So my question is that , is there a way to continue the dispatched gesture and also allow other touch events on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the event stream is always valid, we only allow one stream through at a time, so any gesture from either a service or the user cancels others that are already in progress.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a link where I can understand this better?

Comment: My answer is similar to what's in the javadoc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#dispatchGesture(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback,%20android.os.Handler)